# Image Map in HTML page is not giving responsive output

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, imagemap

I am trying to display one image in html page , in that image i have 6 circles on that all 6 circles i want make them clickable.

I have achieved that functionality but it is static.
It means that whenever i am viewing that image in my phone all the clickable circles are not in the proper places.

How can i make image map responsive.

Below is the code i am using

```
<div>

<img usemap="#planetmap" width="588px" height="471px"   style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;" src = "domains.png";>

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="327,70,66" href="#" target="_blank" alt="" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="160,165,66" href="" target="_blank" alt="" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="490,166,66" href="" target="_blank" alt="" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="162,358,66" href="" target="_blank" alt="" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="490,358,66" href="" target="_blank" alt="" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="327,451,66" href="" target="_blank" alt="" />
</map>
<div>


</div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min"></script>
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('map').imageMapResize();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this link really good?"jquery.rwdImageMaps.min"

Answer (score 1):

What I do when trying to make something responsive on a web page is either one of two things, I a. use 'Media Queries', or b. use a front-end CSS framework like 'Bootstrap'. Personally I prefer the latter.

Here is an example of a media query which will reduce the size of the specified image when a certain condition is met (this goes in your CSS file):

```
@media (min-width: 700px)
{
    .map { width: 400px; height: 400px; }
}
```

Now if the device's width meets the criteria, the specified css code will be applied to the .map element.

This is a very basic example but I think it will get you started on the right track. You can modify your media query to change the dimensions of the map to fit different screen sizes. See here for more detailed information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries